# How to send FCM notification to app from web by API (V1)

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My code can send data and recive response code 200(OK) from API. But my device can't recive message.
If I test by firebase console my device can recive message.
And I test send from OAuth2.0 Playground. The results are the same my code.
I don't know my problem. Please help.

And I need code for generate API Key from JSON file.
(**JSON file from firebase console)

This is my code in php.

```
<?php
function sendFCM() {
  // FCM API Url
  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nanagroup/messages:send';

  // Put your Server Key here
  //Now I get API key from OAuth2.0 Playground
  $apiKey = "ya29.a0AfB_byB3orl0ZHoWQl_KYGObHiytKRj3WeMDmlYOuuUBVKlqHsploLlrxBExC2w5_Ux7-YgwUioFgw_F5VbQjouCDtUOGuB2y65ikUmCaMsMyYC1C8nBD4wAuSIhFSDx120BtCiSashwGC0AHZe2b9kP7lTVJc3H4WPlaCgYKATASARISFQHGX2MiX-xa0oLOMvIAiYH3thEf6w0171";

  // Compile headers in one variable
  $headers = array (
    'Authorization:Bearer ' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
  );

  // Add notification content to a variable for easy reference
  $notifData = [
    'title' => "Test Title",
    'body' => "Test notification body",
  ];

  $notifMessage = [
    'token' => "elGCwBHhSK2roeM-VysEIm:APA91bFma3hQgndwueeyIfd91acHonvGSo-T8u_VfQAfSgMGdgBYP0HTX5c9JIbvHQjMZVPv9XD0y1liuXli0K3KG6CQVbqcZrbGuM19atV2CDNvFInsxnpEkeDxJNtAQauLpS9MmgOC",
    'data' => $notifData,
  ];

   $apiBody = [
    'message' => $notifMessage
  ];

  // Initialize curl with the prepared headers and body
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($apiBody));

  // Execute call and save result
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  print($result);
  // Close curl after call
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
sendFCM();
?>
```

And this my response.

```
{ "name": "projects/nanagroup/messages/0:1699761107535994%2aad7fdff9fd7ecd" }
```